# Get highest two variable values and name from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to get the two highest variables and the variable name from a group of data. Here is what I've come up with so far in the attempt to get the first highest.

```
var one = 5
var two = 6
var three = 5
var four = 10
var five = 2
```

(or as an array:  var array = [one, two, three, four, five]

```
if (one > two && three && four && five) { 
console.log('One Highest')
 }


if (two > one && three && four && five) { 
        console.log('Two Highest')
         }

if (three > one && two && four && five) { 
        console.log('Three Highest')
         }

 if (four > one && three && two && five) { 
            console.log('Four Highest')
          }

 if (five > one && two && four && three) { 
            console.log('Five Highest')
          }
```

Once I know which is the highest I need to be able to add points to another variable based on the winner...

Example:

```
if var one is the greatest value {
 // add points to var one items
 thingOne +50
 thingTwo +50
}

if var two is the greatest value {
 // add points to var two items
 thingThree +50
 thingFour +50
}
```

If possible I'm also trying to be able to find the second highest score and var name.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Where is the array

Comment: try `Math.max`...

Comment: @rassar That solves the value but how do I get the corresponding var name?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Can you describe the entire problem you are facing? Why do you want second highest score and var name?

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi Why are you doing them as separate variables in the first place? Just use an array.

Comment: @HopefulLlama The goal is to loop through a set of variables and get the highest two values. However based on which two variables are the two highest I need to add points to corresponding items.

So If var four and five are the highest I need to add points to items related to four and five.

If four is highest add 50 points to item20
if five is 2nd highest add 25 points to item30

Comment: What is the relation between the two highest variable and adding points? Add how many points?

Comment: I need to know the two highest variables in order to add points to related items. The related items only get points if the original var was the highest two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I will have a go, but not sure. This is first attempt ever trying to answer a questions. I presume this is JavaScript. Not sure if this will be right

```
array myArray[] = {4, 6, 8, 3, 8, 7};//Array like this no ?
var firstHighest = array[0];//We say any of them is highest
var secondHighest = array[0];//We say any of them is second highest
int x;//for loop 

for(x=0;x<=array.length;x++){
if(array[x] > firstHighest){
firstHighest = array[x];
}
} 
//After this we have highest I think

//Now lets get second Highest

for(x=0;x<=array.length;x++){
if((array[x] > secondHighest)&&(array[x] != firstHighest)){
secondHighest = array[x];
}
} 
//We now have second highest i think
//We can now use them two variables
//I pretty sure there are functions that do this for you though
```